# How to get parameter names in view by route values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC 4.
Is there a way to get action parameter names by route value.

```
    public ActionResult Index(string id, string staffId)
    {
        ViewData.Add("idList", idList);
        return View();
    }
```

Suppose I have this "index" action. And the controller name is "TestController".

In the view, can I use the route value controller = "Test", action = "index", to get the parameter name list {"id, staffId"}. This route values are dynamic in view.

Comment: you question is confusing. do you mean you want to get the list of parameters used for that route, or pass values to those parameters, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the way my self. I see my question confusing. But here is what I am looking for.

```
    var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(
            x => x.GetName().Name == "XXXX").Single();

    var controllerTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.Name == Model.Controller + "Controller");

    var controllerType = controllerTypes.Where(x => x.Namespace.Contains(Model.Area)).Single();

    var action = controllerType.GetMethod(Model.Action);

    var parameters = action.GetParameters();
```

But I am still not sure, if it's correct to put this logic in View.

Comment: you example is using reflection to get the parameters of the function Index of your controller. If your scenario is that you want to list the parameters in a view then sure this would do it. if you want to use them in the view then your return View(parameters);. if not then not sure why you want this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Model. You shouldn't be putting everything in `ViewData` like that.

Create just a simple object that will contain the data that you need for the View, and pass the information that way.

Comment: while I agree i'm not sure this answers the question, though I'm not sure what the OP is

Comment: If you're trying to get information from the **C**ontroller to the **V**iew, you use a **M**odel. You can use ViewData and TempData all day long if you want, but you're ignoring one of the main points of the infrastructure you're using. I do agree that the OP is really unclear with what they're looking for.

Comment: I am not asking about the ViewData. You can ignore it.